# A good book on Many-body physics

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, many-body

So, I have two options on my mind:
(a) *Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics: An Introduction* by Bruus, Flensberg
(b) *Many-Particle Physics* by Gerald Mahan

I have studied a few chapters from Bruus, Flensberg in my undergraduate courses. Since different books have different formalism/symbols/expressions, I wanted to stick with one for the rest of my research career. Any suggestions other than these are also welcome.

Edit: The book recommendations on the possible duplicate question are different from the question asked here. Altland and Simons is a good book but is quite different from the books I have mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book recommendations for second quantization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72335/)

Comment: Mahan is broad and intuitive but can be quite sloppy with units and hidden assumptions behind equations in various places. I have found Bruus&Flensberg to be slightly easier to work with. Also, good luck in sticking with one formalism/symbols/expressions for the rest of your career if you want it to be a long one ;) I'm reminded of [this comics](https://xkcd.com/927/)