How do I go about self-studying 2nd quantization approach to QFT?
I would like to self-study QFT (2nd quantization). I have across  across some questions but haven't seen any related to the second quantization. Please suggest books/courses for the same.

All of them use second quantization in some form or other. It is made very explicit in non-relativistic QFT books, like Fetter & Walecka.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72335/2451 and links therein.
